# Sortable w/ Selectable Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-plugins

Is it possible to be able to have sortable elements, but still allow users to copy/paste the text inside the elements?

```
<div class="sortable">
   <div class="pseudo-sortable">Foo</div>
   <div class="pseudo-sortable">Bar</div>
   <div>other stuff that i don't care if a user 
        can't copy (maybe images or buttoms)</div>
</div>
```

I can easily do:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({cancel: '.pseudo-sortable'});
```

This will allow me to select the text in the browser and copy/paste if I want.  However, this also makes it so that the person can't drag/drop.  So I think what I'd like is to start off with the cancel but if the mouse goes a certain distance outside the container, then the pseudo-sortables are no longer canceled.  Does that make sense?

If this is not possible my last option would be to apply a trigger that switches containers between sortable and non-sortable, so that they can select the text, but I'd prefer to minimize ui clicks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about putting your text in a `<span>`?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 5</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 6</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 7</span></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    cancel: "#sortable li span"
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6uXx8/

Comment: So, this allows for the text to be selectable, but not draggable.  What I like is for it to be selectable, but it turns into draggable after a certain distance (~100px) outside the container box.

Comment: What I wanted wasn't easily possible, so I guess this would be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a [handle](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-handle). The idea is that you can only start dragging the item from the handle, which could be, for example, an icon inside the element.

Comment: I know that's possible, but I want the whole content, text included, to be draggable.  Only, I want it so that the text is also copy/pasteable.  So applying a min-distance move before the element becomes draggable if gripped by text.

Comment: You want a lot ;) but seriously, I stronly suggest you decide whether the text is selectable or draggable; doing both seems awkward and users will be confused IMO.

Comment: Yes, this is something a little more advanced, to reduce the number of mouse clicks.  Currently, I have a lock/unlock button that switches the class between draggable and non-draggable, which works.  Just trying to reduce those mini-buttons and make everything better.

Comment: Sorry I never got back to you, I don't have a page available to show.  The only thing I could liken it to is iGoogle (or any draggable/sortable widget).  Instead of having a handle, I want it so that a user can click anywhere inside to drag, however, I also want the text to be copyable.  It's confusing, but to a user, it would be better.